# Comparison between roots of $p$ and $q$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two monic polynomials with non negative roots such that $p(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ and $q(x)=f(x)-h(x)$. If we know all the roots of $f,g,h$, can we say anything about largest positive and smallest positive root of $p$ and $q?$

I have totally  no idea how to think over it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What's an eigenvalue of a polynomial, just a root? Anyway, it will depend a bit on the relative positions of the roots. If the roots of $g$ interlace with those of $f$ then you can probably make a decent estimate about the roots of $p$.

Comment: @ Ian, thanks for pointing. Now I edited the question.

Comment: Even If the roots of g interlace with those of f, how to compare roots of $p$ and $q.$

Comment: Are the roots of $f,g,h$ also assumed to be non-negative?

Comment: There is very little that you can say because roots of $p(x)$ correspond to places where $f(x)=g(x)$, which is usually unrelated to the roots.